# Yandex карты пропадают метки при зуме

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карта-api

при зуме пропадают метки, если увести карту в сторону, а потом вернуться то часть меток может отобразиться.. 
код взял из примера яндекса, просто добавил свои точки

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [54.809,56.1],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 32,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true
        });

    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
        objectManager.add(geoJson);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5b9qud4w/2/
пример с моими точками

Comment: Если вы про то, что до окончания драга кластера не появляются, то это by design.

Comment: @flapenguin я про то, что если начать начать увеличивать, то точки ведут себя очень странным образом, а на определенном зуме и вовсе пропадают. Часть таких точек можно вылечить просто уведя карту в сторону, а потом вернувшись к месту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как оказалось у всех точек совпадал ид, поэтому были такие проблемы.. сделал разные ид и все начало корректно работать